# Python script on server vs. command line

Tags: python

I have a simple hello world python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """\
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

I uploaded it to my server, which has python installed, yet when I visit it in the browser by hitting http://myserver.foo/script.py , I see the script in it's entirety in the browser window. Am I doing something wrong? I want to just see 'Hello World!'...

Comment: This is really a server configuration question, not a Python question. (You might mention *which* server you are using.)

Comment: Do you have mod_wsgi installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stupid (but mandatory) questions:
1. Do you have this in either your `conf` file or an `.htaccess` (assuming Apache)?

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py

Options +ExecCGI
```

2. Have you `chmod`'d the file to `755`?
3. Is Python at `/usr/bin/python`? (It could be `C:\Python32\python.exe`)

---

Some notes:

1. I generally recommend `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/python`. It is more error-proof.
2. You should be using WSGI if at all possible.

Comment: I'm guessing hes missing 1, 2 and side note 2.